# Let $E \subset ℝ^n$ open and $f:E→ℝ^m$. Then is $f$ cont. diffb. on $E$ $⇔$ all the partial derivatives $D_jf_i$ exists on $E$ and are cont. on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $E \subset ℝ^n$ open and $f:E→ℝ^m$. Then is $f$ continiuous differentiable on $E$ if and only if all the partial derivatives $D_jf_i$ exists on $E$ and are continuous on $E$.

I don't understand the prove given in my book. I'm looking for a proof with a lot more steps explained. I really don't understand 90% of the proof. Does someone know a website where this theorem is explained in detail ?

Another question, is it normal to give first year math students proofs like this ???

This is the prove of $⇐$ provided in my book and which I don't understand:

> Let $a∈E$ en let $r>0$ such that $x∈E$ if $|x-a|<r$. We need to prove
>   that:
>
> $$\lim_{h→0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-(h_1(D_1f)(a)+...+h_n(D_nf)(a))|}{|h|}=0\tag{2.29}$$
>
> Let $h∈ℝ^n$ with $|h|<r$ and write $v_k:=h_1e_1+...+h_ke_k$. Then
>
> $$f(a+h)-f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^n(f(a+v_k)-f(a+v_{k-1}))=\sum_{k=1}^n(f(a+v_{k-1})+h_ke_k)-f(a+v_{k-1}))$$
>
> For every $k$ use the mean value theorem on the function
>   $g_k(t):=f(a+v_{k-1}+te_k)$. So there exist numbers $θ_j∈(0,1)$ such
>   that
>
> $$f(a+v_{k-1}+h_ke_k)-f(a+v_{k-1}=g_k(h_k)-g_k(0)=h_kg_k'(θ_k)=h_k(D_kf)(a+v_{k-1}θ_kh_ke_k)$$
>
> Then $$f(a+h)-f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^nh_k(D_kf)(a+v_{k-1}+θ_kh_ke_k)$$
>
> Thus
>   $$f(a+h)-f(a)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}h_k(D_kf)(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}h_k((D_kf)(a+v_{k-1}+θ_kh_ke_k)-(D_kf)(a)$$
>
> Thus $$\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-(h_1D_1f)(a)+...+h_n(D_nf)(a)
>  |}{|h|}≤\sum_{k=1}^{n}|(D_kf)(a+v_{k-1}+θ_kh_ke_k)-(D_kf)(a)
>  |\tag{2.30}$$
>
> Let $ϵ>0$. There exist $δ>0$ such that for every $k$,
>   $|(D_kf)(x)-(D_kf)(a) |≤ϵ/n$ if $|x-a|<δ$. Let $|h|<δ$ then
>
> $$|v_{k-1}+θ_kh_ke_k|=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|h_j|^2+θ_kh_k)^2\right)^{1/2}≤|h|<δ$$
>
> Therefore the right side of (2.30) is smaller then
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(ϵ/n)=ϵ$. This shows that (2.29) holds.

Comment: Well, you can start by sharing the proof you are given. There is the following result. Denote, given a linear transformation $A$, it's norm by $\| A\|=\sup\{Ax:|x|\leq 1\}$. Then if $a_{ij}$ are the coefficients of its matrix, $$\|A\|\leq \left(\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2\right)^2$$ This is the generalization of "continuity coordinatewise $\iff$ continuity".

Comment: Well $⇒$ is not given, we are supposed to do that ourself. I will write out $⇐$. It is quite long.

Comment: Wait, isn't this the definition of continuously differentiable?

Comment: @JavierBadia Well, you *might* say that $\bf f$ is continuously differentiable if ${\bf f'}:\Bbb R^n\to\operatorname{hom}(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$ is continuous w.r.t. to the norm I mentioned above.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Oh, that makes sense.

Comment: @JavierBadia So you see how if each coordinate is continuous, using the above shows $\bf f'$ is continuous. The converse should be more or less obvious. Of course each $a_{ij}$ is a function in this case.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I've added the proof.

Comment: @Kasper OK, and what exactly is what you don't understand?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I don't understand why it suffices to prove 2.29. I don't understand why you can rewrite $f(a+h)-f(a)$ that way. I don't understand why he goes for this $g_k$ function. etc. et.